# How to allow multiple users in local network to share a single MySQL database

Tags: mysql

How to allow multiple users in local network to share a single MySQL database? We even have option of share drive, if it will help.
we are using C# windows application as front end

The **limitation** is that we do not have acces to our main server. The server is with the other ofice department  and we do not want to indulge that department in our project. So, we are on LAN and have a **shared drive** between us.
And we want to use this database common to multiple users in our office (aprox 100 users) which will use our C# windows application to view data and to enter data.
Can we do something on Share Drive? I am not sure..
Hope it will make some sense..

Thanx

Comment: What OS runs under your server?

Comment: Windows. There is no exact server. I just want to give access from my Mysql database to some other systems on network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an excellent guide for unix based servers :

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

the same passages are needed for a windows system, you need to enable remote access and eventually grant permissions on a defined IP.

Remote sharing of the database is disabled by default for security reasons.

EDIT: 
if you are in the same network, then you may just grant permissions I.E.:

```
GRANT SELECT ON mydb.* TO devel2@192.168.1.102 identified by 'mypassword'
```

Answer (score 3):

MySQL handles this situation out-of-the-box. Each client connects from *wherever* and the DBM handles the details. Make sure the server is configured correctly and that the specific database allows connects from other than 127.0.0.1.

Whatever you do, do *not* use file sharing to try and run multiple copies of MySQL against a single database -- that way lies madness and tears. There are lock files that try to prevent this type of abuse, but I've acutally seen people try to "get around" this.

Answer (score 0):

As long as they have network access to the server and you have at least MySQL 5 (5.0.2), can't you just [create](http://www.databasef1.com/tutorial/mysql-create-user.html) [users](http://crunchbang.org/archives/2008/04/17/create-mysql-user-accounts-from-the-command-line/) for them?

```
CREATE USER 'new_username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password_for_new_username';
```